# Displaying maps.googleapis.com JSON data (specifically weekday_text and open_now) on personal website

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Firstly, I apologize as this is probably a very simple question, I just have no experience with this, so I am unsure of where to start.

So I have a small business website I am designing, and I am tasked to pull the data from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=IDHERE&fields=opening_hours&key=APIKEY

When I navigate to the link with my information in it, I can see the JSON data, but I am struggling in what the correct approach to do this.

So far I have attempted an Ajax way

```js
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=IDHERE&fields=opening_hours&key=APIKEY",
        crossDomain: true,
        method: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'application/json',
 
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
        
    });
```

I have also tried the DataType as jsonp, json, script and headers as "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest2" and "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"

When I attempt to run the code on a local html page, I keep getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked errors in the console.

Am I approaching this in the correct way? or should I look at it in another way? The website in question is based on the Twig templates, so I could work something in PHP.

I have zero experience with PHP and Javascript. My experience lies with web-design as well as C#, so this is unfamiliar territory for me.

Thank you for any suggestions/help

Comment: Check this url google has complete solution with php https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. I did see it, and dismissed it because of the MYSQL portion, but I will read through the document.

Comment: There are several ways in that link, js, php and php xml.